# Asp.NET dropdownlist autopostback

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

I have a dropdownlist with autopostback enabled. and have a repeater where i populate checkboxes from database.

If i set the autopostback to true then when selecting a value checkboxes lose its value...

Any workarounds on this?

Here is the code :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" runat="server"  class="pop" AutoPostBack="true" >
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptD" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
        <td valign="top" >
        <input type="checkbox" class="al" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Where do u populate the checkboxes? on postback on declaratively in markup? more details please. code snippets would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is because you are DataBinding the Repeater not only `if(!IsPostBack)` but also on postbacks. Therefore the checked state will be overriden.

So do this in `Page_Load`(assuming C#):

```
if(!IsPostBack){
   DataBindRepeater();
}
```

Whereas `DataBindRepeater` is a method that sets the DataSource property and `DataBind` the Repeater.

You might also want to use an ASP.NET [Checkbox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx) instead of the html `input type="checkbox"`. The checked state is reloaded only if it's a server WebControl that implements [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I do have !postback in my load method but still same result. also why rebind when it is not saved in database yet?

Comment: @Samin: Have you noticed my second hint? Use an ASP.NET Checkbox server control instead of your html-input since the checked state is reloaded on postbacks only from server-controls that implement IPostBackDataHandler.

Comment: @Tim I am using value and name and id in html checkbox to show the them from database. what is the equivalent of value and name for asp checkbox as it says it is not valid attribute?

Comment: @Samim: An ASP.NET-Checkbox does not have a value property. But if you really need one, add it manually: `CheckBox1.InputAttributes.Add("Value", 2);`. If you don't need this attribute on clientside but on serverside, use `CheckBox1.Attributes.Add("Value", 2);`. This will not be rendered as html but stored in ViewState and accessible from serverside.

Comment: @Samim: You may also want to look at the [CheckBoxList control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) as an alternative for your Repeater-Checkbox combo.

Comment: Im not entirely sure how to do this here is what im doing right now : <input type="checkbox" class="allergy" onclick="javascript:ACBoxClicked();"  id='Checkbox1' value='<%#Eval("DAID")%>' name='<%#Eval("Type")%>'  />  <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text='<%#Eval("Type")%>' runat="server"  />

Comment: cant I store the user selected values in session/viewstate or in an object?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://forums.asp.net/p/1370809/2866640.aspx Have you tried to use an asp.net checkbox?

Comment: @Tim, I added runat=server to the html checkbox and seems to work fine now :), thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds indicative of populating the checkboxes in Page_Load. Is that the case? If you're populating the controls in Page_Load then you'll want to wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  // populate your controls from data
}
```

Otherwise, they'll get re-populated with each postback. When you have an autopostback or click a button or perform some other action on the page which initiates a postback, Page_Load is called before the event handler. So in effect, this is happening:

1. User navigates to the page
2. Page_Load clears and populates the checkboxes
3. User chooses an item in the DropDownList (triggering a postback)
4. Page_Load clears and populates the checkboxes
5. DropDownList autopostback handler is called

(On a side note... Please look into using AJAX for dynamic client-server interaction like this.  Autopostback makes for a poor user experience, and as you're discovering also makes for a difficult development experience.)

Comment: @Samim: Can you show more code, then?  When you debug through the code, at what point are the values lost?  Do you have ViewState disabled for the controls in question?  Are any other values retained?  If so, what is different between the controls?